# ng-class is not working as I expect it to be

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-grid, ng-class

In ng-grid, I am using the following cell Template,

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="{\'red\': {{row.getProperty(col.field)}} > 15 , \'yellow\': {{row.getProperty(col.field)}} > 5 && {{row.getProperty(col.field)}} <= 15}">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}} </div>'
```

However, it does not appear how I expect it to be. Sometimes it applies the class 'red' when the value is 0. I am not sure why it is behaving so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-class` directive doesn't process `{{}}` interpolation directive

```
ng-class="{'red': row.getProperty(col.field)}
```

Comment: You can also remove the escapes `ng-class="{'red': row.getProperty(col.field)}"`

Comment: @John Glad to help you.. Thanks :)